# Is the following 3-manifold always a trivial I-bundle over a surface?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact, orientable and irreducible 3-manifold with with boundary consisting of two incompressible components $N_0,N_1$, with $N_i \stackrel{f_i}{\cong}  S_g$ for some diffeomorphism $f_i: S_g \to N_i$, where $S_g$ is the closed orientable surface of genus $g $. I wonder if the following is true:

> If $f_0 \simeq f_1$, i.e, if the $f_i $ are homotopic  as maps from $S_g$ to $M$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to $ S_g \times [0,1]$.

I have the following idea for a proof: Since $f_0 \simeq f_1$, there is a map $f: S_g \times [0,1] \to M$ with $f(x,i) = f_i(x)$ for $i=0,1$. In particular, we have $f_0 = f \circ i_0$ with $i_0: S_g \to S_g \times [0,1]$  the natural inclusion of $S_g$. Since $f_0$ is $\pi_1$-injective and $i_0$ is a homotopy equivalence, $f$ must be $\pi_1$ injective. I would be done once I've shown that $f$ is also $\pi_1$-surjective, since this implies that $f$ is indeed homotopic to a homeomorphism.

Intuitively, this *should* be the case, but i cannot come up with a formal proof of this. Does anybody have an idea, or a counterexample ?

Comment: Perhaps a possible approach: using Morse theory your bordism can be decomposed into handles. If $M$ is not a product, then it should be obtained by adding handles to $S_g\times I$. And then your homotopy can be made transversal to the handles of that decomposition.

Comment: Could you explain your notation?  Your question makes no sense to me.  I assume $S_g$ is a surface, but $\cong$ is what?

Comment: I have changed the notation. Everything should be clear now

Comment: Show that $f$ is a degree 1 map. Degree 1 maps must be surjective on the fundamental group (since they can't lift to a non-trivial cover).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by degree here ? I assume you are talking about the induced map in *second* homology, since we have manifolds with boundary here. Necessarily, $H_2(M)$ should always be $\mathbb Z$, but why is this given ? And why does *this* degree again coincide with the covering degree of a covering map ?

Comment: $f$ has degree 1 as a map of manifolds with boundary, ie the degree of the map on $H_2(M,\partial M) \cong Z$. This is because the degree of the map on the boundary is 1. That the degree is the same as the covering degree is a basic fact that you can find in textbooks.

Comment: You probably mean $H_3(M,\partial M)$, don't you ? I was aware of the equality of homological degree and covering degree for *closed* manifolds, I guess the generalization to compact manifolds is straightforward.

Comment: Yes, $H_3$. Serves me right for answering questions before waking up.

Comment: It is a remarkable skill, being able to even write coherent setences while fast asleep. A small mistake does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows, fairly easily, from the hypothesis of irreducibility and from the "annulus theorem" (see page 130 of Jaco-Shalen's book "Seifert Fibered Spaces in 3-Manifolds").  You can remove the hypothesis of irreducibility if you are willing to use the Poincaré conjecture.

Comment: I thought the Poincare conjecture was a theorem these days?

Comment: @IgorRivin - Sure.  But the original poster might want to avoid using a giant hammer of a theorem, when a tiny spatula of an assumption will do the same job.

Comment: Actually, my understanding has been that the whole "irreducibility" hypothesis was invented to weasel out of the PC, so now that we don't need to weasel any more...

Comment: You mean only in context of this question? Because in general, it seems to me that even to this day, irreducible 3 manifolds are far better understood than general 3 manifolds.

Comment: @IgorRivin - Yes, correct.  But we wouldn't want to waste a good weasel!

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has already been answered, I would like to shortly explain the idea on how to prove that $f$ is $\pi_1$-surjective, as it has been established in the comments below my original question. The result then follows from the classification of Haken manifolds (See Hempel's "3 Manifolds", for example).

I will use the notation from the origianl question:

Let $X:= S_g \times [0,1]$, and $x$ some basepoint in $X$, let $G := f_*(\pi_1(X,x)) \subset \pi_1(M,f(x))$ and let $g: N \to M$ be a covering map corresponding to the subgroup $G$. The map $f$ then lifts to a map $h:X \to N$, so that we have $g \circ h = f$. Moreover, $N$ is also a (possibly noncompact) manifold-with-boundary; the *homological* degree $deg(g)$ is therefore well-defined and its absolute value coincides with the covering degree of $g$. In particular, since $deg(f) = deg(g)*deg(h)$, we must have $deg(g)= \pm 1$. That is because $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism on the boundary, implying $deg(f)= \pm1$. But then $g$ must be the trivial covering map, so $G = \pi_1(M)$. Therefore, $f$ is indeed $\pi_1$-surjective.